# Regex with fixed start and end and repetitive groups inside

Tags: regex, vb.net, repeat

VB2012: I have a string I want to parse out. It has a fixed start and end string but inside there are repetitive strings.

Input string looks like this with much more of the same type of data between START and END.

```
START;data[0][1]="2000";data[0][2]="2015-09-25";data[0][3]="XYZ";END;
```

My current regex looks like this

```
(data\[(?<row>\d{1,2})]\[(?<col>\d{1,2})]="(?<val>.*?)";)
```

That works great and matches the repetitive strings inside:

```
Match Number    Match Text                      Group 1                             row col val
0               "data[0][1]=""2000"";"          "data[0][1]=""2000"";"              "0" "1" "2000"
1               "data[0][2]=""2015-09-25"";"    "data[0][2]=""2015-09-25"";"        "0" "2" "2015-09-25"
2               "data[0][3]=""XYZ"";"           "data[0][3]=""XYZ"";"               "0" "3" "XYZ"
```

I want to make the match a bit more accurate by matching the START string, then repetitive strings, then and END string. My attempt has been of the form:

```
START;(data\[(?<row>\d{1,2})]\[(?<col>\d{1,2})]="(?<val>.*?)";)*END;
```

But that gives me an output where the different groups are on their own and not part of a bigger match. I'm stuck on what I should try.

Comment: Check the `match.Groups["row"].Captures` and `col` & `val` (sorry, that's C# syntax) collection - everything's there :)

Comment: On my first try each match I can do match.groups("val"). with the second try there is only one match and on this match I guess I have to do match.Groups("val").Captures as you mentioned. The first is intuitive to me but the second is not which is what i think is hanging me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your example:

```
START;data[0][1]="2000";data[0][2]="2015-09-25";data[0][3]="XYZ";END;
```

along with your second regex:

```
START;(data\[(?<row>\d{1,2})]\[(?<col>\d{1,2})]="(?<val>.*?)";)*END;
```

So, what do we get here?

The pattern is wrapped in `START;(`...*[values]*...`)*END;`, and you're using a `*` quantifier. There are further capture groups in the *[values]* part.

So, a match looks like this:

```
START;data[0][1]="2000";data[0][2]="2015-09-25";data[0][3]="XYZ";END;
           R  C   VVVV       R  C   VVVVVVVVVV       R  C   VVV        <-- groups
      \________________/\______________________/\_______________/      <-- [values]
\___________________________________________________________________/  <-- full match
```

The *[values]* part of the regex matches 3 times. `R` is the value captured by the `row` group, `C` is what's captured by `col`, and `VVV` is what's captured by `val`.

In such a case, most other regex engines would throw away all but the last capture, and you'd get only the values `0`, `3` and `XYZ` from your match.

But .NET supports multiple captures per group. So you can extract *all* the captured substrings, for each iteration of the enclosing `*` quantifier.

- Each item in `Match.Groups` corresponds to a capture group in the pattern (e.g. the `(?<row>`...`)` group).
- Each item in `Match.Groups("row").Captures` corresponds to a given capture in an iteration of a quantifier *during the match*.

Which means, when a given capture group is used several times during a match, you'll get several captures for it.

---

Contrast it with the first regex:

```
(data\[(?<row>\d{1,2})]\[(?<col>\d{1,2})]="(?<val>.*?)";)
```

Let's look at the matches:

```
START;data[0][1]="2000";data[0][2]="2015-09-25";data[0][3]="XYZ";END;
           R  C   VVVV       R  C   VVVVVVVVVV       R  C   VVV        <-- groups
      \________________/\______________________/\_______________/      <-- whole matches
```

Each match has only one capture instance for each capturing group.

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I think I get it now. Trying to determine which one is best for me. I think I can also do two matches if I'm stuck on the first type. First match to START;<data>END; and on that match I can do another regex with the data value as the input.